# AJAX redirect to another php file and pass javascript variable to that same php file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am new to Ajax. I have here a function that when a button is clicked, you should be redirected to `id.php` and at the same time pass the value of `clicked_id`.

Javascript code:

```js
function clicked(clicked_id){
    window.alert("clicked");
    window.alert(clicked_id);

    $.post('id.php',{ID:clicked_id},
        function(data){
            window.alert("here");
            window.location='id.php';
        });
 }
```

Inside my id.php,

```
<?php
    $clickedID = $_GET['ID'];

    echo 'here at id.php';
    echo $clickedID;
?>
```

Now the problem is that `ID` in `id.php` cannot be identified.

Please help me. I already tried both `$_POST` and `$_GET`.

I believe that the problem here is in the passing of the variable.

Comment: You're accessing `$_GET` instead of `$_POST`, but you're making the request with `$.post`.

Comment: @4castle I already tried $_POST but still, it wont work

Comment: Change window.location='id.php';  to window.location.href='id.php';

Comment: An `AJAX` request is meant for backend processing, not opening a page with variables. If you wanted to load a page with `GET` variables you could remove the `POST` / `GET` call and just use `window.location='id.php&id='+clicked_id;` See [the Ajax Introduction for more info](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no need for ajax if you wanna pass the id to the id.php after redirection

```
function clicked(clicked_id){
       window.alert("clicked");
       window.alert(clicked_id);
       window.location='id.php?id=' + clicked_id;
}
```

in id.php you can get the id like this:

```
<?php $id = $_GET['id'];
```

Comment: You are a lifesaver! Thanks a lot. It works now without causing a problem with my buttons.

Comment: No problem just please mark the response as solved thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
function buttonClicked() {

            $.ajax({
                url: "id.php", //url for php function
                type: "POST",
                data: {'clicked_id':clicked_id}, // data to sent
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data)
                {

                }
            });
        }
```

And in your id.php file:

```
$_REQUEST['clicked_id']
```

Comment: use $_POST or $_REQUEST

Comment: what is in the data type? I'm sorry. I am just starting to learn Ajax

Comment: datatype of data that you are sent